Double integral $\int\limits_{y = 1}^\infty {\int\limits_{x = 1}^y {\frac{1}{{xy{{\left( {y - x} \right)}^{\frac{1}{5}}}}}dxdy} } $
I am trying to evaluate this integral
$$I=\displaystyle\int\limits_{y = 1}^\infty  {\int\limits_{x = 1}^y {\frac{1}{{xy{{\left( {y - x} \right)}^{\frac{1}{5}}}}}dxdy} }$$
By using CAS checks, the result should be : $$\pi\sqrt{10 \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)}$$
But I don't know how to process, I tried to integrate with respect to $x$ but the antiderivative is nasty, here:
$$\displaystyle\frac{-\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) \log \left(\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) \sqrt[5]{y} \sqrt[5]{y-x}+2 (y-x)^{2/5}+2 y^{2/5}\right)+\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \log \left(-\left(\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \sqrt[5]{y} \sqrt[5]{y-x}\right)+2 (y-x)^{2/5}+2 y^{2/5}\right)+4 \log \left(\sqrt[5]{y-x}-\sqrt[5]{y}\right)+2 \sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}} \left(4 \sqrt{5} \sqrt[5]{y-x}+\left(\sqrt{5}-5\right) \sqrt[5]{y}\right)}{20 \sqrt[5]{y}}\right)+2 \sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{10} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)} \left(\frac{4 \sqrt{5} \sqrt[5]{y-x}}{\sqrt[5]{y}}+\sqrt{5}+5\right)\right)}{4 y^{6/5}}$$
I just want to ask a hint, or a substitution can reduce the given integral to an "easier" version to deal with. Thank you for your time.

Consider the transformation $T:(1,\infty)\times(1,\infty)\mapsto(0,\infty)\times(1,\infty)$ given by
$$T(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x/y\\ y\end{pmatrix}$$
Its Jacobian matrix is given by
$$J_T(x,y)=\Big|\operatorname{det}\begin{pmatrix} \frac1y & -\frac{x}{y^2}\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\Big|=\frac1{|y|}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_1\frac1y\Big(\int^y_1\frac{dx}{x(y-x)^{1/5}}\Big)\,dy 
&=\int^\infty_1\int^\infty_1 \mathbf{1}_{(1/y,1)}(x/y)\frac{y}{yx}\frac{1}{y^{1/5}}\frac{1}{\big(1-\frac{x}{y}\big)^{1/5}} J_T(x,y)\,dxdy \\
&= \int^\infty_1\int^1_{1/v}
\frac{1}{v}\frac{1}{u}v^{-1/5}(1-u)^{-1/5}\,dudv\\
&=\int^1_0 \Big(\int^{\infty}_{1/u} v^{-6/5}\,dv\Big)u^{-1}(1-u)^{-1/5}\,dv\,du\\
&=5\int^1_0u^{\tfrac15 - 1}(1-u)^{\tfrac45-1}\,du=5\operatorname{Beta}(1/5,4/5)\approx 26.72398\ldots
\end{align}
Edit:  By Euler's reflection formula
$$5\operatorname{Beta}(1/5,4/5)=5\frac{\Gamma(1/5)\Gamma(4/5)}{\Gamma(1)}=\tfrac{5\pi}{\sin(\pi/5)}= \pi\sqrt{10(5+\sqrt{5})}$$

Beautiful solution, thank you and +1. Hope you have a good day.

Sorry Mittens, they voted to close my question.

@OnTheWay: It happens, at issue is the subjective concept of "context" in a posting, and sometimes curators don't care about the complexity of trickiness of a question. Anyway, you can help reopening your question with some edits where you tell where this problem comes from and why you are interested in solving them, your background, etc. One last thing that may be helpful is to include the tags "real analysis" and "calculus" to your posting. Many users' have golden badges in those subjects (including the ones you currently tag) and would be sensible to vote to reopen. Regards!
